# How do I get a warning before killing a temporary buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

More than once I've lost work by accidentally killing a temporary buffer in Emacs.  Can I set up Emacs to give me a warning when I kill a buffer not associated with a file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a function that will ask you whether you're sure when the buffer has been edited and is not associated with a file.  Then add that function to the list `kill-buffer-query-functions`.

Looking at the documentation for [Buffer File Name](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html) you understand:

- a buffer is not visiting a file if and only if the variable `buffer-file-name` is nil

Use that insight to write the function:

```lisp
(defun maybe-kill-buffer ()
  (if (and (not buffer-file-name)
           (buffer-modified-p))
      ;; buffer is not visiting a file
      (y-or-n-p "This buffer is not visiting a file but has been edited.  Kill it anyway? ")
    t))
```

And then add the function to the hook like so:

```
(add-to-list 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'maybe-kill-buffer)
```

Comment: Also, is there any way to make it exclude other buffers, such as *Open Recent*?

Comment: You could put the following inside the `and' after `buffer-modified-p':

    (not (equal (buffer-name) "*Open Recent*"))

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun maybe-kill-buffer ()
  (if (and (not buffer-file-name)
           (buffer-modified-p))
      ;; buffer is not visiting a file
      (y-or-n-p (format "Buffer %s has been edited.  Kill it anyway? "
                        (buffer-name)))
    t))

(add-to-list 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'maybe-kill-buffer)
```